# How to change void* parameter inside of a thread function

Tags: c, multithreading, void-pointers

I am creating a thread for each request from the client to get the files on the server. Thread function normally gets a void pointer; but I need to give it a char pointer as a parameter and want it to be populated with the file names by the thread function.

Code creates a thread:

```
pt_ret = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, getfiles, (void*) thread_buff);
pthread_join(thread_id, pt_ret);
```

Def. of thread function:

```
void *getfiles(void *ptr) {
    /* ... */
    char buff[256]; // populating that local buffer with the file names
    // ptr should be as a return of buff
}
```

I have tried different things but each time after that thread completes, thread_buff becomes just 'Q'.

Comment: there is no need to cast any pointer to `void*` in C.

Comment: Can you post more code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast it to a char*, since you know it actually *is* a char*:

```
void *getfiles(void *ptr) {
    /* ... */
    const char *ptr_char = (const char*)ptr;
    char buff[256]; 
    memcpy(buff, ptr_char, 256); //just as an example, check the sizes.
    //you could also strcpy, that's up to you
}
```

Or you could also just work on the buffer pointed by ptr, without copying it, so it's accessible after the thread has ended:

```
void *getfiles(void *ptr) {
    /* ... */
    char *buff = (char*)ptr;
    /* do stuff with buff. */
}
```

Comment: Editted, check the second solution.

Comment: The cast is not needed and obfuscating. Simply assign it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you want to use data stored in your thread's "buff" var AFTER the thread ends. Which is not possible, the data only exists on the stack temporarily.

You have to pass a char**ptr, and populate it with a copy of buff, like:

```
*ptr = strdup(buff)
```

And pass (void*)&thread_buff instead of (void*)thread_buff to the thread function.

Comment: Why would he need to pass a pointer to a pointer to char? The buffer is still available after the thread has ended if he uses a char *

Comment: So that thread_buff points to the copy of thread's buff var. But I must admit op's comment 'ptr should be as a return of buff' is confusing.